# Date Time Picker For ionic 1?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic 1. I need date/time picker component that is the same as implemented in ionic 2.

I found [this](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/angularjs/datetime/date#theme=ios) but it's not free.

Comment: https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker or https://github.com/katemihalikova/ion-datetime-picker UI is different but fulfills requirement

Comment: thanks , but i see it  before , but i want it as the same UI.

Comment: You know what I recommend using simple <input type="datetime-local"> which will load native date time picker for Android or ios devices.

Comment: @Bassam check below url : http://www.clearlyinnovative.com/ionic-framework-custom-formly-template-using-datepicker-plugin

Comment: thanks you for your answer , but $cordovaTimePicker will give us  native UI  using in ios or in  android , so ui for android will be different .

Comment: you can use **[angular bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepickerPopup)**

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea which date/time picker you have used, but in ionic 1 , you can use their built-in

In your html

```
<input type="date" data-date="" data-date-format="DD MMMM, YY" value="YOUR_SELECTED_DATE" ng-model="YOUR_DATE_MODAL">
```

furthermore, If you want to change the format of date you can change it via custom javascript function.